# How to add a vertical line in a horizontal bar chart?

Tags: excel, charts

I have to following chart with dates as the x-Axis:

[image: Horizontal bar chart]

How can a white, vertical line on top of the bars chart be displayed at today's date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is detailed step-by-step guide: http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/DummySeries.html#AddLine

My own sample file shared as an example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8uyxqpiq2blv6t9/Charts_H-V_Lines.xlsx

Hope that's somehow helpful.